# request.getParameter("bldgId") is working fine in InternetExplorer, but in Firefox it is fetching value as "null"

Tags: java, jsp, post, request, jsp-tags

this is my index.jsp page
**index.jsp**

```
    <body>
    <jsp:useBean id="po" scope="request" class="Forms.POInfoForm" />
    <form name="frmEntry" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="mediator.jsp" onSubmit = "return confirmSubmit();">
    <table border="3" bordercolor="#000000" id="tableName2" width="80%"> 
        <%  
        if (po.getBldgId() != null) {
            for (int j=0; j < po.getBldgId().length; j++) { 
            %>
                            
                            <input type="hidden" value="" name="bldgitemId">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="33%">
                                    <font color="#000000">  Building: </font>
                                    <div id="buildingInfo<%=j%>"/>
                                    <script language="JavaScript">
                                
                              createBuildingList(<%=j%>, buildingInfo<%=j%>, <%=po.getBldgId(j) %>);
                                    </script>

                            <td width="33%">
                                <font color="#000000">  Sub Account: </font>
                                <div id="subAccountInfo<%=j%>"/>
                                <script language="JavaScript">
createSubAccountList(<%=j%>, subAccountInfo<%=j%>, <%=po.getBldgId(j) %>, <%=po.getSubAccountId(j) %>);
                                
                            </script>
                             </td>
                             </tr>
                           </table>
```

after clicking the submit the request will go to another jsp page mediator.jsp, where i am checking the value is fetched or not.

**mediator.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Mediator
</title>
</head>
<jsp:useBean id="po" scope="request" class="Forms.POInfoForm" />
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<h1>
Mediator JSP
</h1>
<%System.out.println("bldgId is-->"+request.getParameter("bldgId")); %>
<%System.out.println("subAccoutId is-->"+request.getParameter("subAccountId")); %>
//some actions
```

below is the two tags generated from the index.jsp page(inspect browser)

[image]

Note: i am able to fetch the above two field values in IE but not in Edge,Chrome, please help me,
Thanks in Advance!..

Comment: Your code looks okay to me .. Can you just remove `accept-charset="utf-8"` and check onces ?

Comment: removed but still fetching "null" value, i am shocking why i am unable to fetch the values even when i inspect(index.jsp) it is displaying correctly name="bldgId".

Comment: Check if normal input values get pass i.e `bldgitemId` ..if yes then something wrong with select maybe.

Comment: able to fetch other fields, but what is wrong with those two select tags

Comment: can you share your full code for index.jsp page ? So that i can test it on my end .

Comment: you can test above one with submit button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221945/discussion-between-swati-and-chiluka-bharath).